# Intercepting outgoing messages in Akka

Tags: scala, proxy, akka

I have an actor that schedules the sending of messages based on timestamps in the messages. Currently, I have to explicitly send the messages to the scheduler.

How can I make the scheduler transparent (proxy) for my actors? Intercepting the outgoing messages of some actors, and redirecting the decorated message to the scheduler.

Comment: I think you'll have to give more specific detail before anyone can attempt to answer this. Show some code examples.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do this completely transparently. I'd probably make a `tellScheduled(scheduledActor: ActorRef, message: Message)` helper method on a trait and mix it in the classes needing this behavior.

If you're feeling adventurous you could probably wire it in a as an override on `!` as well, which would feel pretty transparent to the user.

The other option would be to "wrap" the receiving actor in the scheduler - how that looks would depend on how you're getting a reference to the worker.

Net-net, the route you go will largely depend on the code. Do you want the scheduling to be "controlled" by the receiver, the sender, or the routing infrastructure?